# What is the easiest and most accurate way to average feet/inches?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using the format #'##, what would be the best way to average values using a formula?

For example: if I have the following values -

[image]

The average of these heights should return 5'01. What would be the best way to achieve this using a formula? Thank you!

Comment: If this was my spreadsheet I would add formulas in a separate column that converted one such value to its corresponding foot value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(JOIN("'", TEXT({"", "0."}&SPLIT(AVERAGE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(A1:A3, "'"), 
 "select Col1+Col2/12"), "offset 1", 0)), ".")*{1, 12}, {"0", "0#"})))
```

[image]

Comment: `4'09` meaning `4 feet 9 inches` is not the same as `4.09 feet`, it's equivalent to 4+9/12 feet, which is 4.75 feet.

Comment: Also - the result should return in the format of #'##

Answer (score 1):

Given your post data, which runs A1:A3 (and I'm assuming further down than Row 3):

`=ArrayFormula(INT(AVERAGE(FILTER({VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+"))+VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+$"))/12},A:A<>"")))&"'"&TEXT(ROUND(MOD(AVERAGE(FILTER({VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+"))+VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"\d+$"))/12},A:A<>"")),1)*12),"00"))`

In summary, `REGEXEXTRACT` is used to separate the left and right portions of the original data. `VALUE` converts them from strings to numbers. `/12` and `*12` do the conversion from inches to decimal and back to inches. The ampersand (`&`) symbols are used to concatenated the final `INT`eger portion, the feet symbol (`'`) and the converted decimal-to-inches value. `TEXT` assures that the final result is in the format `00`.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a formula that might solve your problem but it is a bit long.

> =ROUND(ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE((REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "(\d)'\d+")*12)+REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "\d'(\d+)")))/12)&"'"&MOD(ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE((REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "(\d)'\d+")*12)+REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "\d'(\d+)"))),12)

What the formula does is it calculates the values of A1:A3 into inches and gets the average before converting it again into feet'inches format. Please see result below.

[image]